# Is there any proper way to send a POST request through React using fetch()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, api

I am getting url as **None** on the API server side and the API is working fine when tested with POSTMAN and other scripts but the **problem happens when sending the request in React**.

```
const imgLoad = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    image_url: imageurl    //image url stored in a variable & I tried using a string but the problem is still there
  })
}

fetch("http://127.0.0.1:7000/emotion_detection/detect/", imgLoad)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({emotion: data}));
```

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: It’s not an error but the value of image_url becomes None on the API server side, so it’s the problem with the way I’m sending the request.

Answer (score 0):

Used **POSTMAN** tool to find the correct implementation way from ReactJS.

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("image_url", `${this.state.input}`);

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formdata,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://127.0.0.1:7000/emotion_detection/detect/", requestOptions)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```